# Android app to view the network usage history over the past 12 hours

Tags: android, network-monitor, internet

I'm looking for an Android application that can show the network usage history over the past 12 hours. I want to see the graph of the upload and download usage over the past 12 hours (or more). It should be able to plot even if the app does not have the focus, i.e. is not in the foreground, i.e. is in the background. Any license or price is fine.

I tried [Network Speed - Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network) but it only plots when the app has the focus.

Comment: If you're still looking for alternatives, maybe my collection of apps for [Statistics on data usage](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics#group_93) can help you. Haven't tried any of those myself, though, so I cannot give a clear recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit user [pH9654](https://www.reddit.com/user/pH9654) [pointed me](https://redd.it/1840i9k) to [GlassWire Data Usage Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=glasswire&c=apps) (gratis). It allows users to view the network activity for a given day by groups of 3 hours:

[image]